# R Time Series: Median of few minutes at the beginning and end of certain group

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate median of 2 minutes at the beginning and end of certain groups in one of the columns. To make it more clear I am going to explain on a base of the sample data:

```
Time <- c("2015-08-21T10:00:51", "2015-08-21T10:02:51", "2015-08-21T10:04:51", "2015-08-21T10:06:51", 
          "2015-08-21T10:08:51", "2015-08-21T10:10:51","2015-08-21T10:12:51", "2015-08-21T10:14:51", 
          "2015-08-21T10:16:51", "2015-08-21T10:18:51", "2015-08-21T10:20:51", "2015-08-21T10:22:51")
x <-  c(38.855, 38.664, 40.386, 40.386, 40.195, 40.386, 40.386, 40.195, 40.386, 38.855, 38.664, 40.386)
y <-  c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b")
data <- data.frame(Time,x,y)
data$Time <- as.POSIXct(data$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

So in this case the median of column `x` of **2 minutes Time** at the beginning (`"2015-08-21T10:00:51", "2015-08-21T10:02:51"` so for **x** = 38.855, 38.664 **median** = 38.7595) and end ( `"2015-08-21T10:08:51", "2015-08-21T10:10:51"` so for **x** = 40.195, 40.386 **median** = 40.2905) for level `a`, further for level `b` at the beginning (`"2015-08-21T10:10:51","2015-08-21T10:12:51"` so for **x** = 40.386, 40.195 **median** = 40.2905) and end (`"2015-08-21T10:20:51", "2015-08-21T10:22:51"` so for **x** = 38.664, 40.386 **median** = 39.525)...

The result of this calculation would be best to get as a new `data.frame` like:

```
y median1 median2
a 38.7595 40.2905
b 40.2905 39.525
```

Thanks for any help!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using libraries `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can do something like this:

```
data %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  slice(c(1, 2, n(), n() - 1)) %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(firstGroup = ifelse(row_number(y) < 3, 'medianGroup1', 'medianGroup2')) %>%
  group_by(y, firstGroup) %>%
  summarise(medianValue = median(x)) %>%
  spread(firstGroup, medianValue)
```

Output looks as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

       y medianGroup1 medianGroup2
  (fctr)        (dbl)        (dbl)
1      a      38.7595      40.2905
2      b      40.2905      39.5250
```

Note, I am showing each step explicitly in the code, but it could be condensed further.

Comment: Thank so much for help. However this is a sample data (in my real data i need to perform median of 10 minutes). Is it possible to groupby somehow on base of time, rather than on rows number? I am not sure if i understood right Your code, but it seems you performed median on base of row number?Thanks